# Deleting records from MySQL inside foreach loop - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm checking a project and I found this code that is suppose to delete records from `MySQL`, despite this is not the best aproach to achieve this I have to make this works, but for me is fine, that's why I'm here, because I don't see the error or what is wrong with this code, is not displaying errors, warning, nothing I tested the code directly in `PHPMyAdmin` and it works well, so this is the code...

```
$get_records = mysql_query('SELECT id_detail FROM my_table WHERE user_id = "'.$user_id.'" AND last_date BETWEEN "'.$date1.'" AND "'.$date2.'"') or die (mysql_error());

$array_details = array();

while ($details = mysql_fetch_array($get_records)) {

    $array_details[] = $details['id_detail'];

}  


$array_details = array_unique($array_details);


foreach ($array_details as $id_detail) {

    $delete_detail = mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' AND id_detail = '".$id_detail."'") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

I got two records in the same table with the same ID detail (this works that way), so If I get the ID correcly with the query inside the `foreach` loop it should delete all the records with that `id_detail` and `user_id` doesn't matter if in the query I say between which dates get those IDs, it deletes only one, and that one is which has the date between that range

I have no idea why is not deleting both, some idea about what I'm missing?

NOTE: As I said before if I do that query directly in `PHPMyAdmin` it works fine and if I do from PHP it delete only one.

Comment: Maybe it's getting only one id instead of two (in this script)

Comment: Why would you use PHP as a middle-man for this? You're sidestepping MySQL's built in logic and increasing your queries by n+1. Why not just do a single `DELETE FROM {logic}` statement? Even if for some reason you do want to have PHP logic in between all of this stuff, you have an array of primary keys (presumed), so why not leverage `WHERE IN` to reduce queries?

Comment: if you always have 2 entries in the table, deleting by offset may solve it something like i=0; foreach($a as $b){ $my_query to del $b[0]; $i++;}

Comment: @xYuri not always will be 2

Comment: @Blake I know this is not best aproach but even with `WHERE IN` only deletes one

Comment: sorry, i meant its one or more, my solution will work if you applied it the right way, but i recommend what @Blake recommended

Comment: WHERE IN might delete one row at a time, I'm not familiar with the execution plans in MySQL, but in SQL Server it typically converts this to a WHERE EXISTS execution which is set based.  If EXISTS is available in your MySQL version, I'd recommend retrofitting Rebecca's answer below to use that.

Comment: And if you're not super deep into your application, you should really consider prepared statements using PDO or Mysqli to prevent sql injections. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: to stay safe from `sql inection` 2 simple  things to do 1) never use `mysql_*` functions, that means any function starts with `mysql_`, instead you can use `mysqli_*` functions. 

also always escape the values submitted by users by using, `mysqli_real_escape_string($connection_name, $string_to_escape);`

Answer (score 0):

Does replacing that code with this query work for you?

```
$delete_detail = mysql_query("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' AND id_detail IN (SELECT id_detail FROM my_table WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."' AND last_date BETWEEN '".$date1."' AND '".$date2."')") or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: I will try this

Comment: This adds values like `'.2.'` instead. It's syntactically correct, which is an improvement, but misses the goal.

Comment: Still not working, I tried this but as before it deletes only one >:]

Comment: @tadman, agree, should be `("DELETE FROM my_table WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND id_detail IN (SELECT id_detail FROM my_table WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND last_date BETWEEN '$date1' AND '$date2')")`

Comment: also +1, for attempting to help